# How to convert pdf into text file using itext liberary

Tags: itext

Below is my code for converting a pdf file into a text file.
The code successfully runs, but it doesn't generate the resulting text file (Sample.txt). Can anyone shed some light on this? 
The code is partly based on an example of the first iText in action book...

```
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

public class ConvertPDFToTEXT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.open();
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Data Dictinary A4.pdf");
            PdfDictionary dictionary = reader.getPageN(1);
            PRIndirectReference reference = (PRIndirectReference)
            dictionary.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
            PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference);
            byte[] bytes = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
            PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(bytes);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("Sample.txt");
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (tokenizer.nextToken()) {
                if (tokenizer.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TK_STRING) {
                    buffer.append(tokenizer.getStringValue());
                }
            }
            String test=buffer.toString();
            StringReader stReader = new StringReader(test);
            int t;
            while((t=stReader.read())>0)
                fos.write(t);
            document.add(new Paragraph(".."));
            document.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `catch (Exception e) {}` - are there any `Exceptions` going into that black hole? Furthermore, in general your approach (collecting PDF Strings as they are) will produce utter gibberish as you completely ignore positioning and font encodings.

Comment: Below is error caught by above catch statement

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference'

Comment: Can you also provide the stack trace? And the iText version you use? I only see one place in your code where something is cast to `PRIndirectReference`, but there the assumed original type `Class` does not make sense. Probably it's somewhere underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which example are you using? If it is the the one from page 575 you will read the following:

*"What you have here is a poor man’s text extractor. It works well for this example, but it won’t work with most PDF files that can be found in the wild. Many aspects should be taken into account if you want to use iText as a text-extraction library."*

The next chapter is named "Why iText doesn’t do text extraction" - so iText in that version was limited when it comes to text extration. In the end you have basically two possibilities:

1. Upgrade to a new version of iText which provides much better text extraction capabilities
2. If you must stick with version 2.1.7 then have a look at the PdfTextExtractor.java instead of what you are doing. Here is some code found in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588485/itext-pdftextextractor-gettextfrompage-exception-error-reading-string-at-file-p):

   ```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(yourInputstream);
   PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);        
   int pagenumber = reader.getNumberOfPages();

   for(int i = 1; i<= pagenumber; i++) {
       System.out.println("============PAGE NUMBER " + i + "=============" );
       String line = extractor.getTextFromPage(i);
       System.out.println(line);
   }
   ```

   But as you can see in the other post depending on the PDF, extraction doesn't always work in that version...

Comment: *But as you can see in the other post depending on the PDF extraction doesn't always work in that version.* - Text extraction classes in iText up to the early 5.x versions essentially were a mere proof-of-concept.